# Mozilla Add-on development: Accessing LAST USED or LAST CHANGED fields in password manger

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

My add-on needs to access stored credentials. In this I want to get the credentials that was changed or used recently. I see that I have LAST USED and  LAST CHANGED fields but how do I access those fields in my javascript?

I searched and also tried ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/passwords ) but I couldn't get anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get a list of all the currently stored login informations:

```
var lm = Cc["@mozilla.org/login-manager;1"].getService(Ci.nsILoginManager);
var arrOfLogins = lm.getAllLogins();
var numberOfLogins = arrOfLogins.length;
console.info('arrOfLogins:', arrOfLogins);

var myObjs = [];
for (var i=0; i<numberOfLogins; i++) {
    var pushObj = {};
    pushObj.username = arrOfLogins[i].username;
    pushObj.password = arrOfLogins[i].password;
    pushObj.hostname = arrOfLogins[i].hostname;
    arrOfLogins[i].QueryInterface(Ci.nsILoginMetaInfo);
    pushObj.lastUsed = new Date(arrOfLogins[i].timeLastUsed);
    pushObj.lastChanged = new Date(arrOfLogins[i].timePasswordChanged);
    myObjs.push(pushObj);
}

console.info('myObjs:', myObjs);
```

If the user has a master password, you have to prompt them to fill it out, otherwise the above iwll fail im pretty sure.