# Simulate captive login with greasemonkey using firefox saved password

Tags: firefox-addon, greasemonkey, autologin

I have written GreaseMonkey script to automate captive portal login.

```
document.getElementById("username").value="myUserName";
document.getElementById("passwd").value=B64.encode("myPassword");
document.form.submit();
```

Browser's inbuilt password manager can log me into web-based captive portal only if I'm on actual captive login URL. (say http://192.168.1.1/login.html). But what if login-page appears while I am on stackoverflow.com. In this case, I need to enter my password, then I get redirected to same page which I was on, and foolish browser offers me to save password for stackoverflow.com

Is there any way to programmatically retrieve passwords from browser password manager. I found LastPass can retrieve my stored passwords in this way.

**What I wanted to achieve?**

1. Auto-Login (without need of hitting login button)
2. Using Browser's inbuilt password manager.( I can set master password, I can use Sync)
3. Make browser able to detect captive login page. (Using `@include *`, in greasemonkey script)
4. Dont want to save password in plain-text.

Comment: Not possible with Greasemonkey.  Use [a login framework](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15269327/) or write a full Firefox add-on.

Comment: I think this is a bug in the firefox login manager no? Please share your thoughts and Ill file a bug on bugzilla for you so we can get some official help

Comment: Btw this is how to get all the information stored in the firefox password manager: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32193516/1828637 if the user has a master password though you cannot get around it and will have to use the firefox prompt for unlock (which will give user the master password input box and on succesful unlock it will give you access)

Comment: @Noitidart I already filed a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1199572) but it seems limitation rather than a bug.

Comment: Interesting thanks for the file and link to.